# how to display no. of character user can type and how many characters user had typed in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How can we display the count of input characters entered by the user and how many characters user can type in that **TEXTFORMFIELD** in Flutter? Like this [image]

image credits : [blog link](https://uxdesign.cc/ui-cheat-sheet-text-fields-2152112615f8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add maxLength property (it will show the writtenCharacters/totalLimit)

```
TextFormField(
  maxLength: 45,
)
```

Or you can also have alternative (it will not show the writtenCharacters/totalLimit), but for this you need to import

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(45),
  ],
)
```

Comment: But I need to use TEXTFORMFIELD not TEXTFIELD

Comment: Thanks , Already I am using it(the 2nd one); but I want to display it as well..



Update :: Thanks the 1st one works. my bad

Comment: Then 1st one can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a `TextField` and achieve what a `TextFormField` do by saving the input of the TextField to a variable on text changed

```
TextField(
          maxLines: 3,
          maxLength: 30,
          onChanged: (value) {
             _content = value;
            },
          ),
```

and send _content on your form submit

With a TextFormField you can have the number of input character by passing an
`TextEditingController` to the `TextFormField`

```
final _myTextEditingController = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
                controller: _myTextEditingController,
                maxLength: 30
)
```

and show the number of character with

```
_myTextEditingController.text.length
```